# Virtual Host in XAMPP

Tags: apache, xampp, vhosts

I have XAMPP running on Windows. My whole Partition E is the DocumentRoot, and I have configured it all to listen to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost for performance issues. I can reach my projects with 127.0.0.1/project1 for stuff that lies on E:\project1. Works fine.

My hosts file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1
```

Now I'd like to setup a virtual host for a different customer, and it should listen to a different address in the browser, like 'new.server'. Also, it should look in a different directory: f:/newserver.
I'd like to reach these new projects with new.server/project2 for stuff on f:/newserver/project2/

I have tried this in the httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost new.server:80>
    ServerName new.server
    DocumentRoot "F:/newserver"
    <Directory "F:/newserver"
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/newserver.local-error_log.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

But things don't work out. I've changed stuff around the conf file but really have no idea what to do, so I'd like to ask for enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that you have uncommented this line in the httpd.conf

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Allso I think there is a problem in your vhosts-file. Try replacing the top row with an ip-adress instead of the server name. Or an asterix since thats an even easier way to do it. 
Something like this should work:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName new.server
    DocumentRoot "F:/newserver"
    <Directory "F:/newserver">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/newserver.local-error_log.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf is uncommented.

Your suggested vhosts-entry does not work.I enter http://new.server into the browser, after a few seconds I am redirected to http://www.new.server/ with an error.
Must I change my hosts-file?

Comment: Sorry...my links were wrong. I meant to say:

I enter http : / / new.server into the browser, after a few seconds I am redirected to http : / / www.new.server/ with an error.

Comment: How does the rest of your vhosts look? You could try and add "127.0.0.1 new.server" to your hosts file, but I doubt thats it. Also what is "127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1" supposed to do?

Comment: I have found out a missing > in your example, in this line:
<Directory "F:/newserver"

Comment: 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 is part of a performance optimization. I replacesd localhost by 127.0.0.1 for better performance. It did work.

Comment: After fixing the vhosts file it did work somehow...both 127.0.0.1 and new.server showed the same directory, my old default htdocs on E:\. Couldn't fix it to show another directory. Then the whole apache configuration fell apart. I could fix it, but my desired configuration with new.server does not work at all.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. So it is working but it directs you to the wrong root directory? If thats the case, then I think I need to see the rest of your configuration to know whats wrong.
There is a default root directory set in httpd.conf which you are probably being directed to. That could be because you have port 80 specified in your vhosts file and maybe you are trying to connect on a different port? 
Which port do you have set up in your apache configuration for http? And when browsing to new.server, add the "http://" in front of the url just to make sure youre going to port 80.

Comment: Yes, it's the wrong directory...thhp://new.server shows the same as http://127.0.0.1 and http://localhost . I see E:\.
I never connected with any other port than 80 (consciously)

Comment: in httpd.conf I can see:
Listen 127.0.0.1:80 and 
ServerName 127.0.0.1:80.
Is that what you meant?

Comment: If youre going to "http://new.server" you should end up in the specified document root. But if you're not then its probably cause you dont get a match on that host and it directs you to the default document root instead. Changing the "<VirtualHost new.server:80>" to "<VirtualHost *:80>" should have made the match possible, but there may be more problems somewhere else in your configuration. There is in fact some log-files you could check out for more info or if you could send me the rest of your config and I could take a look at it. I believe the logs are stored at \xampp\apache\logs\

Comment: No matter what I do, <VirtualHost new.server:80>" or "<VirtualHost *:80>, the behaviour is the same. Actually, I never had any problems with my configuration before. But it doesn't really matter...I have switched to Plan B in the meantime...Let's just say it doesn't work :-/

Answer (score 0):

Besides editing httpd-vhosts.conf, You should add new.server to the hosts file (e.g. C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts). Mine looks like this, not sure about how the last line's "performance optimalization" works, so might not be ideal:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 new.server
127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1
```